# Is the `tan` function returning an incorrect result?

Tags: haskell

I'm doing calculations in my application and I have narrowed my problem to the `tan` function.

```
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /private/var/folders/w2/m3v3grd53s191ys4wjc1tcnr0000gn/T/haskell-stack-ghci/2a3bbd58/ghci-script
Prelude> fov = 0.7853981633
Prelude> tan fov
0.9999999998051035
Prelude> :t fov
fov :: Fractional p => p
Prelude> fov = 0.7853981633 :: Double
Prelude> tan fov
0.9999999998051035
Prelude> :t fov
fov :: Double
Prelude>
```

When I use `tan` on my phone (or any other calculator I've tried), I get this as the answer:

```
0.0137086425
```

So, it would appear that Haskell's `tan` is wrong, but that would be very surprising.

I normally use `Double` in my application, but specifying `Double` as shown above doesn't matter.

I also thought it was a rounding issue and wanted to try rounding to say 4 decimal places, but it appears that you cannot round a Double to anything except in Integer in Haskell?  That seems very weird to me as well.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short**: It uses [**radians**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) for the angle. Your phone probably is set to use [*degrees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)).

The [**`tan :: Floating a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tan) takes an angle in *radians*. So that means that 0.7853981633 radians is approximately 45 degrees.

Your phone probably uses an angle in degrees. We can convert degrees to radians by multiplying with `pi / 180`, so if we calculate this for `0.7853981633` *degrees*, we get:

```
Prelude> tan 0.7853981633  -- radians
0.9999999998051033
Prelude> tan (0.7853981633 * pi / 180)  -- degrees
1.3708642532692942e-2
```

The result for degrees is approximately `3.269294210350715e-11` off, which is probably because you only specify ten decimal places.

Comment: Ahhhh....thanks. Where does the documentation specify it takes radians?  I don't see anything about that here for instance: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ClassyPrelude-0.1/docs/Prelude-Math.html

Comment: Here's the appropriate section of the Haskell 2010 report, FYI https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1400006.4.5

Comment: @CraigTreptow: no, not as far as I can see in the documentation on Hackage itself. Using radians, it however has a quite clean *Taylor expansion* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition), this is also the implementation of the `fsin` on the x86 architecture (https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_114.html). I think most software libraries use radians (the Java Standard library, .NET library, etc.).

Comment: @CraigTreptow In virtually all programming languages, and in mathematics radians is the default. Instead of measuring a round angle as 360 degrees, which is a pretty random arbitrary number, it makes more sense to use 2pi which is the length of a circumference (as a ratio to the diameter). Further several trigonometry equations only hold for radians: e.g. the derivative of sin is cos, but only for radians. With degrees, suddenly a pi/180 factor appears out of nowhere, which is inconvenient.

Comment: @CraigTreptow, that's the usual mathematical convention. The tangent function is a specific function from real numbers to real numbers, which can be understood geometrically if the argument is considered an angle (in radians). To use degrees, one would normally write them out: `tan 45° = tan (pi/4)`.